# Is there an official way to avoid cache for some img image elements?

Tags: javascript, html, caching, server

This has been discussed here and there. I'd made my own solution but I'm wondering if there is some modern official solution by newer standard as ECMAScript 2016.

My solution is a hack in the src property adding a random fake property in the end:

```
function xhrUrlHackNoCache(first) {
    var hack = (first)? "?nocache=" : "&nocache=" ;
    for(let i=0; i<5; i++) {
        hack += Math.floor(Math.random()*10).toString();
    }
    return hack;
}
```

Personally, I think this is ugly...

There is some interesting discussion [here](https://www.py4u.net/discuss/973428). Some I already tested and won't work as header definition, not even when loading the image trough a php script (maybe if I load the image as 64 and create the img object). Maybe manipulating .htaccess file, but I don't have much knowledge about (sometimes I drop my website messing with this file).

The heaven to me will be some img property set to avoid the cache and load this imagem from the file. Is there something like this? What's the best practice in this case today?

If there is nothing new to add to this issue (that has a lot of duplicates) than I might delete it, no problem, but I think is a good idea to update the knowledge about it.

Comment: So you are saying setting no caching headers do not work?

Comment: Generally speaking cache control is done server side, what you have done is known as cache busting, jquery used to use something similar for ajax requests.  But it's obviously not great, because is not really stopping the browser from caching it anyway.  If doing this server side is not an option, modern browsers can use service workers, in here you can control how the cache is done client side.    More info here -> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Service_Worker_API/Using_Service_Workers

Comment: @epascarello Yes, I tried those headers Cache-control, Pragma etc. and didn't work for me.

Comment: Well those cache control headers *do* work when done properly. Use your browser developer tools to make sure that the HTTP requests for the images are returning with the headers you configured on the server. You may have to clear your browser cache before they take effect. That said, cache "busting" as you're doing will work, and browsers *cannot* cache a GET request with a parameter value that they haven't seen before. (Usually I just use `Date.now()`.)